# Using quotient Rule with a problem that has radicals in it(having major issues simplifying...)

Tags: radicals

So i'm trying to remind myself of how to use the quotient rule, and when i try to differentiate the following problem i get major issues:

(2x + x^3) / x^(1/2)

I get to the following point...

((2 + 3x^3)(x^1/2) - 1/2(x^1/2)(2x+x^3)) / x

How in gods name do i simplify this?

Answer (score 1):

The function can be rewritten in a simpler way:
$$
f(x)=\frac{2x+x^3}{x^{1/2}}=2x^{1/2}+x^{5/2}
$$
and the derivative is
$$
f'(x)=2\cdot\frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}+\frac{5}{2}x^{3/2}=
\frac{1}{x^{1/2}}+\frac{5x^{3/2}}{2}=
\frac{2+5x^2}{2x^{1/2}}
$$

You may also use the quotient rule, if you *really* want it:
$$
f'(x)=\frac{(2+3x^2)x^{1/2}-\dfrac{1}{2x^{1/2}}(2x+x^3)}{x}=
\frac{4x+6x^3-2x-x^3}{2x\cdot x^{1/2}}=
\frac{2x+5x^3}{2x\cdot x^{1/2}}
$$
and, after simplifying, you get the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier using logarithmic differentiation:

Set $f(x)=\dfrac{2x+x^3}{x^{\frac12}}=\dfrac{x(2+x^2)}{x^{\frac12}}$. Then:
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac1x+\frac{2x}{2+x^2}-\frac12\cdot\frac1x=\frac1{2x} +\frac{2x}{2+x^2}=\frac{2+5x^2}{2x(2+x^2)},$$
whence
$$f'(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\cdot f(x)=\frac{2+5x^2}{2x^{\frac12}}.$$